# Why jquery sortable not working with canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have two container **sortable1** and **sortable2** and both have multiples canvas. I am using jquery sortable plugin to change position of canvas from one container to another container or within same container and code is:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable_card",
        appendTo:".column_box_one",
        helper: "clone",
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

When I move canvas to change position then it moves without image and text content so could any one suggest that how to fix it?  Actually I want to clone of canvas without loosing any data during sorting.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also you may need to wrap the canvas with a DIV and use a handle.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, I attempted to replicate the issue as you described it. I built the following basic example:

```js
$(function() {
  function draw(cObj, cA, cB) {
    var ctx = cObj[0].getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = cA;
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = cB;
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
  }

  draw($("#canvas-1"), "rgb(255,0,0)", "rgba(0,255,0,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-2"), "rgb(0,255,0)", "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-3"), "rgb(0,0,255)", "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-4"), "rgb(0,255,0)", "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-5"), "rgb(255,0,0)", "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-6"), "rgb(0,0,0)", "rgba(20,20,20,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-7"), "rgb(20,20,20)", "rgba(40,40,40,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-8"), "rgb(40,40,40)", "rgba(60,60,60,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-9"), "rgb(60,60,60)", "rgba(80,80,80,0.5)");

  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 105px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-1" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-2" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-3" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-4" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-5" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-6" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-7" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-8" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-9" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
</ul>
```

This works without issue and does not replicate what you have described. I then added the `helper: "clone"` option and I can immediately see that the helper does not contain the context, as it's a clone of just the canvas container and not it's context.

We need a function to read the context and add it to our clone.

> A function that will return a DOMElement to use while dragging. The function receives the event and the element being sorted.

Source: [Helper | Sortable Widget | jQuery UI API Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper)

```js
$(function() {
  function draw(cObj, cA, cB) {
    var ctx = cObj[0].getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = cA;
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = cB;
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
  }

  function clone(cObj, aObj) {
    if (aObj == undefined) {
      aObj = {};
    }
    var newCanvas = $("<canvas>").attr(aObj).prop({
      width: cObj.width(),
      height: cObj.height()
    });
    var ctx = newCanvas[0].getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(cObj[0], 0, 0);
    return newCanvas;
  }

  draw($("#canvas-1"), "rgb(255,0,0)", "rgba(0,255,0,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-2"), "rgb(0,255,0)", "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-3"), "rgb(0,0,255)", "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-4"), "rgb(0,255,0)", "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-5"), "rgb(255,0,0)", "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-6"), "rgb(0,0,0)", "rgba(20,20,20,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-7"), "rgb(20,20,20)", "rgba(40,40,40,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-8"), "rgb(40,40,40)", "rgba(60,60,60,0.5)");
  draw($("#canvas-9"), "rgb(60,60,60)", "rgba(80,80,80,0.5)");

  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    helper: function(e, item) {
      var li = $("<li>").css("border", "1px solid #000");
      var newCan = clone($("canvas", item));
      li.append(newCan);
      return li[0];
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 105px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-1" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-2" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-3" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-4" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-5" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-6" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-7" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-8" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><canvas id="canvas-9" width="100" height="100"></canvas></li>
</ul>
```

Now we have a proper helper. The helper only exists during sort and is destroyed once the lists are updated. You will want to evaluate how import it is to fully "clone" the item from the source list, cause it's not like draggable where the original is left behind. Sortable has a different logic to it and is designed with the idea that you're moving an item to another location in the list (or another list) and would not want a lingering clone.

If it is really important, consider starting with Draggable and dragging into a Sortable. If you need both to be Sortable, you will have to play with `start`, `stop`, and `update` to create, clone, and re-append the item back to the start, to it's proper position in the original list. It's easier said than done.